# Errors when writing object to binary

Tags: java, serialization, filenotfoundexception

So, here is the code that I have:

```
try  
{  
  PlayerSave save = new PlayerSave(this);   
  save.playerLooks = look;        
  File test = new File("C:/cache/" + playerName + ".tmp");  
  test.createNewFile();  
  FileOutputStream f_out = new  
      FileOutputStream("C:/cache/" + playerName + ".tmp");  
  ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream (f_out);  
  obj_out.writeObject (save);  
  obj_out.close();  
  f_out.close();  
}  
catch (Exception e)  
{  
  e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Upon execution, I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\cache\Bobdole.tmp (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I have also tried using this code:

```
    try
    {
      PlayerSave save = new PlayerSave(this); 
      save.playerLooks = look;      
//      File test = new File("C:/cache/" + playerName + ".tmp");
//      test.createNewFile();
      FileOutputStream f_out = new
          FileOutputStream("C:/cache/" + playerName + ".tmp");
      ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream (f_out);
      obj_out.writeObject (save);
      obj_out.close();
      f_out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, it produces the same error. I am confused as to why this is not working, as everything seems to be right. If you guys can figure out the problem that would be so helpful.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's telling you that the directory `C:\cache` does not exist. The directory must exist in order for you to be able to write files to it. You can either create it manually, or with something like:

```
File directory = new File("C:\\cache");
directory.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 0):

The program can't find your folder.